# PowerPoint VBA Slide Index Where VBA Code Resides

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I need to set the True/False value of an option button in PowerPoint VBA, like this: *ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("optnUrgencyHigh").OLEFormat.Object.Value = True*

The above works great, if the option button is on slide 3, but if someone inserts a slide or 10, before slide 3, this no longer works. I cannot seem to find a way to reference the slide number, for the particular code to reference. I can get the slide number that is currently displayed, but not the slide number where the VBA code resides.

This is further complicated in that the user could have 1 to n number of duplicates of the slide, so while I have the VBA in each copy of the slide, knowing the slide number reference, instead of a hard 3, for example, is eluding me.

Comment: SlideID may help ...  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slide.slideindex

Comment: Yes, SlideID is almost certainly the answer. That solves both problems.  If you know the SlideId of the slide you're after, you can return a reference to the slide with:
activepresentation.slides.findbyslideid(SlideID)